# Is it possible to add domain.de to domain.com in Azure App Service Domains

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1, appdomain, azure-app-service-plans

In Azure App Service Domains is possible to buy a domain.
The following top-level domains are supported by App Service domains: com, net, co.uk, org, nl, in, biz, org.uk, and co.in.

What should I do to use [www.domain.de](http://www.domain.de) instead of [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) in Azure?

I'm aware about the possibility to use [URL redirect or rewrite](http://URL%20Rewriting%20Middleware%20in%20ASP.NET%20Core), but I'm looking for a way to handle this in a more elegant and straighforward way.
At the end, I pay for the domain and for the SSL certificate as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time App Service Domains do not support .de domain purchasing.

You can however purchase your .de domain from a 3rd party domain provide and then setup your domain on your Azure Web App following [these directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

We welcome you to create a feature request on [Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps). The product group reviews the ideas posted on the site to drive their upcoming features.